# Carousel Menu Smoothness and Infinite

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this website: http://store01.titus.biz/

It has a top menu that should scroll on arrow hover, but he moves like i want to but now i want it to keep moving infinitly until a person takes the mouse out.

How can i make this? I've tried carousel, but not successfully.

And other thing, this has "hikups" maybe because of the timer, how can i make this smooth as well?

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="position:relative;">
        <div class="span12 horizontal-category" style="height: 64px">                                 
          <span class="carousel-prev" id="carousel-category-prev"></span>
          <div class="j" style="position: absolute; clip: rect(auto, auto, 500px, auto);">
              <ul class="nav myCustomNav">       
                <?php
                    printCats();
                ?> 
               </ul>
          </div>
          <span class="carousel-next" id="carousel-category-next"></span>                                   
        </div> 
    </div>

<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".myCustomNav li:first").addClass("current");
            $(".myCustomNav li:last").addClass("last");
            $(".last a").width(120);
            carousel();
        });

        var vel = 350;
        var timer;

        function carousel(){                
            $(".carousel-prev").hover(function(){
                timer = setInterval(hover_esquerda, vel);
            }, function(){ clearInterval(timer); });

            $(".carousel-next").hover(function(){
                timer = setInterval(hover_direita, vel);
            }, function(){ clearInterval(timer); });        
        }

        function hover_esquerda(){
            //anda para a esquerda
            if ($(".current").size() == 0){
                $(".myCustomNav li:first").addClass("current");
            }
            if ($(".current").nextUntil(".last").size() == 6){

                //$(".carousel-prev").addClass("disabled");

            } else {                
                $(".myCustomNav .current").removeClass("current").next().addClass("current");
                $(".myCustomNav").animate({
                    left: '-=' + $(".current").prev().width()
                }, 'slow');
            }
        }
        function hover_direita(){
            //anda para a direita               
            $(".myCustomNav .current").removeClass("current").prev().addClass("current");
            $(".myCustomNav").animate({
                left: '+=' + $(".current").width()
            }, 'slow');
        }

    </script>
```

Comment: Whats this im getting when i click your link?? --- Sorry, but content/plugins folder has no writable permissions.

Fix the problem manually.

After you’ve done that, click “Run the install.”

Comment: solved sorry, you can enter now!!

Comment: Good answer below -- also Instead of slow, try fast -- like this -- 'fast', 'linear'); --- looks a bit slow to me

Comment: if i set 'fast' it is really fast and has the same 'hiccups'

Comment: you can stick miliseconds instead of slow or fast and find a sweet spot. slow: 600 -- fast: 200,  -- Default speed: 400

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the 'hiccups' so you can set the easing to 'linear'. The animation will be smooth that way. The standard easing is 'swing' which accelerates and deccelerates the animation.

```
$(".myCustomNav").animate({
                            left: '-=' + $(".current").prev().width()
                          }, 'slow', 'linear');
```

Comment: now i would like to be infinite, this is, if i keep scrolling it set's the first item in the end, and so on...

Comment: @Diogo Severiano -- try fast instead of slow animation, check my comment above -- well if you want infinite scrolling just repeat the menu items about 100 times. Thats a quick workaround

Comment: if i set 'fast' it is really fast and has the same 'hiccups'

Comment: i can have infinite to right but how to left since i'm using the system by using a class to guide me